# Why does Vika have a color video feed?

Tags: oblivion

In *Oblivion* we are shown Vika's work station, and the video feed is black and white.

So why does she have a color feed when Jack is investigating the crash site?

She also gets a color video feed when Jack and his wife are on the top of the Empire State Building when the ship hovers in plain sight.

Is it because she can look through Jack's ship? Does the ship provide a color video feed?

Answer (score 4):

Throughout the film, the feed from the Tet is in black and white, the feed from the bubble-ship is in color and the feed from the drones is the red "Terminator vision."  This serves as a visual shorthand to remind the audience why they are seeing what they are seeing.

The Tet feed is in black and white only because the Tet is playing an imitation game.  It has to seem human enough and low-tech enough to maintain the cover story.  Jack and Vika expect pixelated, black and white video comms from orbit so that's what the Tet provides.  The Tet only had the original communications with Sally as Capcom to work with, so Jack and Vika only ever talk to Sally, and Sally always looks as she looked in that feed.